# Tensorflow Error: "Cannot parse tensor from proto"

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am creating a deep CNN with tensorflow. I have already created the architecture, and now I am in the process of training. When I begin to train the model, I use the command:

```
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

When this command is called, I get the error located below. My intuition tells me that maybe the tensor shape is too large to parse/initialize. I have researched this error and there seems to be little documentation online. **Does this error give enough information to tell what the problem is?** Thank you.

```
2017-10-25 15:07:54.252194: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-
win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1182] Invalid 
argument: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 7
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
}
float_val: 0

2017-10-25 15:07:54.252767: E C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-
win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\common_runtime\executor.cc:644] Executor 
failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: Cannot parse tensor from proto: 
dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 7
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
}
float_val: 0

         [[Node: Variable_737/Adam_1/Initializer/zeros = Const[_class=
["loc:@Variable_737"], dtype=DT_FLOAT, value=<Invalid TensorProto: dtype: 
DT_FLOAT tensor_shape { dim { size: 16 } dim { size: 16 } dim { size: 7 } 
dim { size: 3298 } dim { size: 3298 } } float_val: 0>, 
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
2017-10-25 15:07:54.320979: W C:\tf_jenkins\home\workspace\rel-
win\M\windows\PY\35\tensorflow\core\framework\op_kernel.cc:1182] Invalid 
argument: Cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT
tensor_shape {
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 16
  }
  dim {
    size: 7
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
  dim {
    size: 3298
  }
}
float_val: 0
```

Comment: Looks like it is unable to initialize the variables. Maybe there is some tensor variable of type float that it can't understand? Double check your variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As @Tarun Wadhwa said, tensorflow doesn't allow tensors of size > 2 GB on a single device. Your tensor is of size (19 x 10^9 entries) x 4 bytes = **78 GB** if you're using `dtype='tf.float32'`.

Firstly, you can try using 'tf.float16'. This would halve the size of your tensor on RAM. (It will also add some noise to the weights which will provide a regularizing effect--which is a good thing). You can also try upping your `stride` parameter in convolutional layers.

But you still won't meet the 2 GB allowable limit. In which case, you should distribute your computational graph across multiple GPUs and train the model there. You'll have to re-structure your code by using `with tf.device` statements which is a whole new ballgame. AWS provides 8 and 16 GPU p2 instances on its EC2.

Why do you need to work with such humongous tensors?

Comment: This is the architecture I am attempting to replicate: http://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLP2.png At the end of inception C, I have a tensor of the shape [?,2,2,1,1154]. Because MxNxP is 32x32x7, I assumed I would need a filter size of the shape [16,16,7,1154,1154] for my last deconvolution. Does the image have enough information to tell me that 1154 is too large for my input and output channels?

Answer (score 4):

You can't create Tensors of size > 2GB. This is not a Tensorflow limit but a Google's protobuf limit. One way to solve this problem is to break a large tensor into smaller tensors.

Comment: This is the next line of code that I want to execute. Is this possible if I split the Tensor into smaller ones?          
                                                                                                    DeConnv4 = tf.nn.conv3d_transpose(layer6, filter = w, output_shape = [1,32,32,7,3298], strides = [1,16,16,16,1], padding = 'SAME')

Comment: I am not sure about that. First of all your weight variable is around 19 GB. Even if you split it, I am not sure whether you will be able to fit that into RAM(considering it will create tensors while performing conv operations).

Comment: One thing you can do is create 3298 w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.,shape=[16,16,7,3298,1])) variables and perform conv operations individually(maybe you will have to use external memory since you can't fit 19gbs into main memory) and then combine the result.

Comment: Now that you have indicated that this tensor is abnormally large, it makes me wonderif my architecture is correct. This is the architecture that I am replicating: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1qLP2.png As you can see there are many layers and several indications of concatenation (the orange arrows are shortcuts for residual learning). The reason that there are a large amount of channels is due to the concatenation I am doing. I use tf.concat, I concatenate along the axis of the channels. Does this sound correct? Is there another way to concatenate that wouldnt make my channels so large? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This was the code that produced my error:

```
w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.,shape=[16,16,7,1154,1154]))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

I'm still not sure why this is wrong. It must be that a tf.Variable cannot be this large.